# Django query api: complex subquery

Tags: python, sql, django

I wasted lots of time trying to compose such query. Here my models:

```
class User(Dealer):
    pass


class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    interactions = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserPostInteraction', related_name='post_interaction')


class UserPostInteraction(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='pppost')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uuuuser')
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()


    DISCARD = -1
    VIEWED = 0
    LIKED = 1
    DISLIKED = 2
```

And what i need:

Subquery is: `(UserPostInteractions where status = LIKED) - (UserPostInteractions where status = DISLIKED) of Post(OuterRef('pk'))`

Query is : `Select all posts order by value of subquery`.

I'm stuck at error `Subquery returned multiple rows`

Elp!!))

Comment: your objective is not so clear, try to clarify your needs.
also - your actual tries that yielded the error would help up understand you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly your needs, you can get what you need with such qs:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Sum, When, IntegerField

posts = Post.objects.values('id', 'text', 'date').annotate(
    rate=Sum(Case(
        When(pppost__status=1, then=1), 
        When(pppost__status=2, then=-1), 
        default=0, 
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
).order_by('rate')
```

In MySql it converts in such sql query:

```
SELECT
  `yourapp_post`.`id`,
  `yourapp_post`.`text`,
  `yourapp_post`.`date`,
  SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN `yourapp_userpostinteraction`.`status` = 1
          THEN 1
        WHEN `yourapp_userpostinteraction`.`status` = 2
          THEN -1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS `rate`
FROM `yourapp_post`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `yourapp_userpostinteraction` ON (`yourapp_post`.`id` = `yourapp_userpostinteraction`.`post_id`)
GROUP BY `yourapp_post`.`id`
ORDER BY `rate` ASC
```